# Gradle dependency issue

Tags: java, gradle, neo4j

I've the following dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-rest-graphdb:2.0.1'
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   testCompile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.2.5:tests@jar'
}
```

When executing my tests I encounter an error. I tracked down this error to the following reason:

- `neo4j-rest-graphdb` has a transitive dependency to `neo4j-kernel:2.0.1` which contains an issue which causes my tests to fail.
- This issue is fixed in the current version of `neo4j-kernel`
- However, `neo4j-kernel:2.2.5:tests@jar` seems to use the old kernel version (2.0.1) although I can see that `neo4j-kernel:2.2.5` is also downloaded

So how to configure the dependencies that:

- `neo4j-rest-graphdb` uses its version of the kernel
- while `tests@jar` uses kernel version 2.2.5?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a newer version of `neo4j-rest-graphdb` (2.2.5, for instance)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. According to https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding/releases, 2.0.1 is the most recent.

Comment: Forcing the latest version might help. Check https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force(java.lang.Object[]) for more information. You have to force the latest version for `testCompile` configuration.

Comment: I've added `configurations.testCompile {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.2.5'
}` but I'm still getting the runtime error. I can see the fix in the code of the 2.2.5 version but the stack trace tells me that the old version is referenced. When I set the resolutionStrategy to `failOnConflict` the build fails as expected... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no new version of neo4j-rest-graphdb, because of it has been discontinued.

What you can try is to exclude or replace neo4j-kernel for neo4j-rest-graphdb by Gradle.

Instead of using REST API you can use [Neo4j-OGM](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm), [Spring Data for Neo4J](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/) or [JDBC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc).

Or if you are using another language than Java, there are drivers for [Other languages](http://neo4j.com/developer/java/)

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to tell Gradle to use the recent kernel version for testCompile while using the compile dependency uses its version. Do you have any example code?

Comment: It is intentional that he module has been discontinued, it was a bad idea to start with.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Ouh, haven't found any notice for that on their "project page" https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding ...what are the alternatives? Writing my own REST client? :-(

Comment: It is not a Rest-Client it is a feeble attempt to reproduce an embedded API over the wire :)